# appendTo same div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel-5

I have this problem with Jquery / Dropzone at the moment. After i added an image with dropzone it uploads the picture and add's a div, inside this div i append a hidden input field. The problem is when i upload another image it add's the hidden input field from the second image to both the divs. I hope i'm clear !

Here is my Jquery code that will execute after a image is uploaded:

```
// on success add a hidden field with the img path
myDropzone.on("success", function(file, response) {
  console.log(response);
  $('<input>').attr({
    type: 'hidden',
    name: 'img_path',
    id: 'uploadedImg',
    value: response
  }).appendTo('.action-buttons').next();
});
```

This is the html it should appendTo:

```
    <!-- dropbox -->
<div class="box box-primary">
    <div class="box-body upload-form">
        <h5>Voeg afbeeldingen toe aan uw filiaal.</h5>
        <!-- The fileinput-button span is used to style the file input field as button -->
        <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
            <span>Voeg afbeeldingen toe...</span>
        </span>

        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning cancel">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
            <span>Anuleer upload</span>
        </button>

        <!-- The global file processing state -->
        <span class="fileupload-process">
            <div id="total-progress" class="progress progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0"
                 aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0">
              <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:0%;" data-dz-uploadprogress></div>
            </div>
        </span>


        <div class="table table-striped files" id="previews">
            <div id="template" class="file-row">
                <!-- This is used as the file preview template -->
                <div>
                    <span class="preview"><img data-dz-thumbnail/></span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p class="name" data-dz-name></p>
                    <strong class="error text-danger" data-dz-errormessage></strong>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p class="size" data-dz-size></p>
                    <div class="progress progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0"
                         aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0">
                        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:0%;"
                             data-dz-uploadprogress></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="action-buttons">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary start">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
                        <span>Start</span>
                    </button>
                    <button data-dz-remove class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
                        <span>Cancel</span>
                    </button>
                    <button data-dz-remove class="btn btn-danger delete dz-remove">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
                        <span>Delete</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have no idea how to append the right input field to the right div, i hope someone does can help me !

Comment: Show your html please, preferably make a fiddle

Comment: Obviously if you are going to append to a class, it will append to all divs unless you index the particular div. Use id instead.

Comment: https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/issues/240 read through this issue. it have some comments that are helpful

Comment: @AakashVerma thank you, i think this wil solve my problem !

Answer (score 1):

`'.action-buttons'` will select all elements with `class="action-buttons"`. If there are two of them, both will be selected. Same for three, four five, however many there are. And `.append()` will append duplicate content to *all* of them.

You need to select only the one element of interest, which I'm gussing is the [`:last`](https://api.jquery.com/last-selector/).

Try

```
}).appendTo($('.action-buttons').filter(":last"));
```

Comment: Well explained.

Comment: Thanks @AakashVerma. Of course, you may be correct that it should be `:first` not `:last`. We don't really know. If it's random - first/in-between/last - then we need a major rethink!

Comment: It's not an "of course" but yeah, I understand what you mean. And trust me, if it's random, it's silly - we don't need no major rethink over this :)

Comment: This would work, if it was always the last item but sometimes that's not the case. I right now got the right element that i want, but for some reason dropzone won't let me post anything except the _token..

Comment: I must be missing something. In the demo at http://www.dropzonejs.com/, latest file dropped is always the last one in the box, and I can't spot a configuration option that would change that.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand and say you want to do it to only the first div, something like this

```
myDropzone.on("success", function(file, response) {
  console.log(response);
  $('.action-buttons : first').append('<input type="hidden" name="img_path" id="uploadedImg" value="'+ response +'"></input>');
});
```

As I said in comments, you have to choose a specific div for the purpose, so go for `id` instead.